# Was there ever a package called "BinThis"?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, histograms, databin

I'm working my way through someone's old code and rebuilding it.

In one of the notebooks it appears they used a package called "BinThis" which I cannot seem to find any documentation for or a trace of having existed.

Here's what's going on in the code:

```
Needs["BinThis`"];
BinEdges[{{10}, {1*^-1, 10}}]
DensityHistogram[testData,  {{BinEdges[{40, {0, 3}}]}, {0, 1, .05}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

`testData` is a list of $j$ two-element lists that was defined earlier on in the code $[[n_{1},m_{1}],....[n_{j},m_{j}]]$.
My interpretation is `BinEdges[{},{}]` is a built-in function in the package BinThis.

But as I mentioned I can't seem to find any trace of such a package having ever existed.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at the *Mathematica* function `BinCounts`.

Comment: or [`FindDivisions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html)